# Is there any way in VSCode to suggest a header file by just writing its starting letters?

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense, configure

VSCode is not suggesting the header file after I write its starting letters. I mean that by writing "`<iost`" it should suggest the complete header file.

I reset my laptop earlier because of a corrupt Windows update. Before resetting, it was working completely fine. After resetting, I am now facing some problems. I code in C++.

I expect that it will work after configuring `setting.json`. It is continuously asking me to configure IntelliSense.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the C/C++ extension installed, press `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `P`(or `F1`) to bring up the VSCode command palette, and then type "C/C++: Select IntelliSense Configuration". Afterward, press `Enter` and choose one of the configurations.